# Fragments : what is the best place to measure Views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-lifecycle

I have a fragment and I need to measure location/width/height of its views on screen and pass to some other class.

So what I have is a function which does it, something like this :

```
private void measureTest(){
    v = ourView.findViewById(R.id.someTextField);
    v.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
    int w = v.getWidth();
    ...
    SomeClass.passLocation(loc,w);
    ...
```

The problem is that the location/width/height of views is not ready within fragment lifecycle.
So if I run that function within these lifecycle methods :

```
onCreateView
onViewCreated
onStart
onResume
```

I either get wrong location and width/height measurments or 0 values.
The only solution I found is to add a `GlobalLayoutListener` like this to mainView

```
mainView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new     ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    if(alreadyMeasured)
        mainView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    else
        measureTest();
}
});
```

this gets the job done.. but its just Yack! IMO.

Is there a better way of doing this? seems like such a basic thing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no better way. That code isn't that bad! It's fired as soon as the view is layed out (my terminology might be a bit weird there) which happens right after measuring. That is how it is done in the [BitmapFun sample](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) (see ImageGridFragment, line 120) in Google's Android docs. There is a comment on that particular piece of code stating:

```
 // This listener is used to get the final width of the GridView and then calculate the
 // number of columns and the width of each column. The width of each column is variable
 // as the GridView has stretchMode=columnWidth. The column width is used to set the height
 // of each view so we get nice square thumbnails.
```

Comment: Thanks for info. I agree its not that bad.. just the whole boilerplate code and its readability is a bit frustrating. see also blackbelts answer

Comment: The layout/measuring pass of Android's system is still in the Main UI thread's queue when onActivityCreated is called. Posting a new runnable to that queue probably works, but I am not 100% sure if that queue is always FIFO. Maybe blackbelt knows more on that topic. Personally I prefer to go with the safter option, even if it means a few more lines of code :)

Comment: I've got couple of crashes related to this while using blackbelt solution. From my analysis I came to the same conclusion that on some devices only the listener approach is giving desired guarantee.

Answer (score 6):

inside `onActivityCreated` of your fragment retrieve the currentView (with `getView()`) and post a runnable to its queue. Inside the runnable invoke `measureTest()`